# MYSQL LIMIT on COUNT of DISTINCT row

Tags: mysql, subquery, limit

Is there a way to set a `LIMIT` equal to the `COUNT` of `DISTINCT` entries in a row?  I have below query and it all work but the `LIMIT`.  My table will have a varying ammount of `DISTINCT` seriesID and I want the last Episode of the Last Season in each Distinct seriesID.

`SELECT t1.* FROM myTable.SeriesEpisodes t1
  JOIN (SELECT seriesID, MAX(Season) Season FROM myTable.SeriesEpisodes GROUP BY seriesID) t2
    ON t1.Season = t2.Season AND t1.seriesID = t2.seriesID ORDER BY Episode DESC LIMIT ???`

I tried doing a sub query like below but that errors out.

`LIMIT (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT seriesID) FROM myTable.SeriesEpisodes)`

Comment: won't another `GROUP BY(t1.seriesID)` will produce the same result as your needed?

Comment: You don't have to LIMIT - you're already grouping by seriesID so you're never going to get any more rows than that.

Comment: Right, but it gives me more than the last episode per season (it orders all off them and returns them all), and all I need just that for each separate seriesID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query may return the result you specified. The inline view `t2` returns the maximum Season for each Series.  The inline view `t3` returns the maximum Episode for each Season of each Series. The results from the inline views (derived tables) can be joined to the original table, to retrieve the detail row associated with those maximum values. (This assumes that the `(Series,Season,Episode)` tuple is unique.)

```
SELECT t1.*
  FROM myTable.SeriesEpisodes t1
  JOIN ( SELECT s2.Series
              , MAX(s2.Season) AS Season
           FROM myTable.SeriesEpisodes s2
          GROUP
             BY s2.Series
       ) t2
    ON t2.Series  = t1.Series
   AND t2.Season  = t1.Season
  JOIN ( SELECT s3.Series
              , s3.Season
              , MAX(s3.Episode) AS Episode
           FROM myTable.SeriesEpisodes s3
          GROUP
             BY s3.Series
              , s3.Season
       ) t3
    ON t3.Series  = t1.Series
   AND t3.Season  = t1.Season
   AND t3.Episode = t1.Episode
 ORDER 
    BY t1.Series
     , t1.Season
```

**EDIT**

*--or--*

An equivalent result can be returned with a query like this. Inline view `t2` returns the latest Episode of the latest Season for each Series.

```
SELECT t1.*
  FROM myTable.SeriesEpisodes t1
  JOIN ( SELECT s2.Series
              , s2.Season
              , MAX(s2.Episode) AS Episode
           FROM myTable.SeriesEpisodes s2
           JOIN ( SELECT s3.Series
                       , MAX(s3.Season) AS Season
                    FROM myTable.SeriesEpisodes s3
                   GROUP
                      BY s3.Series
                ) t3
             ON t3.Series  = s2.Series
            AND t3.Season  = s2.Season
          GROUP
             BY s2.Series
              , s2.Season
       ) t2
    ON t2.Series  = t1.Series
   AND t2.Season  = t1.Season
   AND t2.Episode = t1.Episode
 ORDER 
    BY t1.Series
     , t1.Season
```

Comment: Great!  The first one works perfectly!  Is there a pro to using either or of your 2?

Comment: I think the second one is better. The inline view `t2` only returns the max value of Episode for the max Season. The first query, we're getting the max Episode for every Season, which is more rows of "max Episode" than we really need. In terms of performance, I don't think there's going to be much of a difference... for both, we want suitable indexes defined `ON SeriesEpisodes (Series, Season, Episode)`. We'd look at the output from EXPLAIN, and observe performance (making sure we're bypassing the query cache, if that's enabled, by including NOCACHE hint.)

Comment: Cool! They both work and I see the logic behind the second one being a bit better. Performance isn't huge as the table isn't that big (at least yet). Thanks a ton for the detailed response!